# How to make .getDay to return something other than a number?

Tags: javascript

The result shows **"Monday1"** because **.getDay** method displays 1 as Monday.

```
var dob = new Date("April 2,1984");
var weekDay = dob.getDay();
if (weekDay==1) {
document.write('Monday');
}
document.write(weekDay);
```

Is there any way to get rid of the number and leave just Monday word?

Comment: You might be able to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: remove the line `document.write(weekDay);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

Return the name of the weekday (not just a number):

```
var d = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] =  "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
```

The result of n will be:

```
Tuesday
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I guess the issue you are facing is that you'll have to write multiple if else and checks. You can use the below function to get it done once and for all

```
function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date();
  var weekday = new Array(7);
  weekday[0] = "Sunday";
  weekday[1] = "Monday";
  weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
  weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
  weekday[4] = "Thursday";
  weekday[5] = "Friday";
  weekday[6] = "Saturday";

  var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
  alert(n);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with putting an array of weekdays

```
var Weekday_name = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday' ...]
var dob = new Date("April 2,1984");
var weekDay = dob.getDay();
console.log(Weekday_names[weekDay]);
```